# Lagrangian "constant" string length constraint for unwinding string in pulley system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, string

The following is a problem from Patrick Hamill's *A Student's Guide to Lagrangians and Hamiltonians*.

> A string passes over a massless pulley. Each end is wound around a vertical
> hoop, as shown in the figure below. The hoops tend to descend, unwinding the
> string, but if one hoop is much more massive than the other, it can cause
> the lighter hoop to rise. The hoops have masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ and radii $R_1$
> and $R_2$. Show that the tension in the string is $\tau = \dfrac{gm_1m_2}{m_1+m_2}$.
>
> [image]

Q: What is the approach for defining the constant string length constraint, when the string is unwinding as is the case here?

Comment: Any length added to the string implies some added angular velocity (or more specifically angular displacement)

Comment: @SeñorO because of the no slip condition, both the translation and rotation will be accelerated by the unwinding string. But that does not help me constrain this problem further.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/646014/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic Indeed, and that's one of the places where I saw the *C=x1+x2 where C is the length of the rope* constraint, though there is nothing that would specify the rope can't unwind and get longer

Comment: @user256872 well added length will add to the wheels angular & translational energy in the exact same way a wheel would along some distance on the ground. Should be an exact ratio of translational to angular momentum/energyj that I'm too lazy to calculate

Comment: *This problem is constrained to one degree of freedom* I disagree. If we restrain the pulley, each of the hoops would descend independently, hence we have 2 dof. Pulley would only ensure that the rope tension is the same throughout.

Comment: @A.V.S. you have three generalized coordinates, see my answer

Comment: @ACuriousMind: there's a lot to learn in this question. I didn't find the formulation of this constraint as trivial as it may sound. There were several points to be made regarding the physics of the problem. In my post my intention was to explore and highlight those aspects and my use of any eqns was to the same effect. . The interesting points that I am talking about are 1. this is the only case where  both, by themselves perfectly valid, perfect roll and constant length constraints intersect. Inspite of that, there is no perfect rolling happening here. 2. The final tension is agnostic to ...

Comment: @ACuriousMind ...the  sign of the angular terms. This isn't evident from the onset. 3. In spite of the pull from the heavier mass, the lighter mass never goes over the pulley. 4. The sim. helped visually validate our formulation. the  Moreover, the hardest part of the solution - formulation of the equations and solving them isn't posted.

Comment: @ACuriousMind A blatant answer from start to finish or one that doesn't bring any novel physics discussion to future readers is deserving of deletion or closure. In light of the above points, I argue that my answer wasn't in that category. Even so, I do not take your respected critique via deletion lightly - I very much would have liked a nudge, a chance to reedit my answer to better emphasize the above points. A homework-like answer should and must be discouraged and was never my aim.

Comment: @lineage You're still allowed to edit your answer and flag it for moderators to review again and undelete. Also I'm not sure if ACM will be pinged for your comments since they haven't commented on this post.

Comment: @BioPhysicist I was looking for something of the sort. Thanks a lot! So I just flag it post edit? Nothing else like some , ahem, comments to justify reopening?

Comment: @lineage I would just edit your post to only answer the question of the OP rather than supply a full work through of the system. Then I would raise a custom flag on your post.

Comment: @lineage I didn't delete your answer because I thought it was trivial or anything like that. I deleted it because it is our policy (linked in the comment I left when deleting it) to delete detailed answers to homework-like questions, which we consider off-topic here. The community has closed this as such a question, and so I deleted your answer.

Comment: @ACuriousMind thnx for replying. I see. I didn't know that the closure had preceded the deletion. I understand and support the policy you linked - its essential to maintaining the quality of answers PhySE hosts. In light of BioPhysicist's remark, I'll edit the answer to better highlight *only* those features which provide an interesting physics discussion to future readers, and then flag it for your review. In future, if there is a need(hopefully not), I shall do so *before* posting any justifications, like I did here.

Comment: @lineage Your post should just answer the question. The goal isn't to provide interesting physics discussion. This is a Q&A site, not a general physics forum to have discussions.

Comment: @lineage In response to your flag: if the community votes that the question is on-topic, we’ll consider whether to restore the answers.